# Magento 1.9.3 block repositioning

Tags: product, magento-1, blocks, catalog, view

I want to move the product price on the right part.

Screenshot: [image]

The catalog product view root template is 2 columns right. I tried to find the block name using path hints so I can manipulate it from local.xml (test.xml in my case because I'm using custom theme) but I couldn't find it.

`<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>` This is that piece of code that renders the product price in template/catalog/product/view.phtml but I can't figure whether this could be helpful or not.

If someone could tell me which is the right approach, I'd be very thankful!

Answer (score 0):

So you want to move the price after in/out of stock like on this page http://www.bebepunk.ro/excavator-cu-roata-port-cupe-lego-42055-technic.html ?

You can do it through CSS like below.

```
.product-view .product-shop .price-info{
    float: right;
    padding-left: 15px;
    text-align: right;
}
```